# How to set cx and cy with only one function using d3.js, force and network?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

All I found say something like this to change `cx,cy`:

```
  .attr("cx", function(d) {var x... return x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {var y... return y; })
```

But I have a function `F(x,y)` that returns `{X:value, Y:value}`.

As this `F` function is computationally expensive, I can't call it twice.

I need something like this:

```
 node.attr("[cx,cy]", function(d){ return F(d.x,d.y) }
```

Just set `cx` and `cy` calling function `F` just one time for each node.
It is in function `tick()`. And I think `node.attr(...)` calls the function for each node automatically, that's why I don't execute  the function `F` before the `node.attr(...)` line.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pre-compute the values once and store them in your data objects:

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
    var result = F(d.x, d.y);
    d.computedX = result[0];
    d.computedY = result[1];
});
```

And then later:

```
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.computedX; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.computedY; })
```